# copying arrays from a method to main method

Tags: java, arrays

I am asked to write a program that requires three arrays in the main method. The program is supposed to calculate gross wages for given employee ids from user input of the pay rate and hours also from user input. Also, it is asking me to write a method calculateWages with three array parameters: hours, payRate, and wages, which calculates and stores the wages for each employee by multiplying the corresponding hours and pay rates.

Your program should display each employee number and ask the user to enter that employee's hours and pay rate.  After getting the hours and pay rates for all employees, your program should call calculateWages.  Next, your program should display each employee's identification number and gross wages.  Note: the number of employees and the minimum wage should both be named constants.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    double[] employeeID = {5658845, 4520125, 7895122, 8777541, 8451277,1302850, 7580489};   //Employee IDs of which we are calculating gross wages for
    double[] payRate = new double[7];
    double[] employeeWages = new double[7];
    double[] employeeHours = new double[7];
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);      //Needed for keyboard input



    for (int i = 0; i<employeeID.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Employee ID: " + employeeID[i]);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of hours worked: ");
        employeeHours[i]=keyboard.nextDouble();

        //Get and validate hours from user.
        while(employeeHours[i]<0)
        {
            System.out.println("Error. Hours worked must not be negative.");
            System.out.print("Please enter hours worked: ");
            employeeHours[i]=keyboard.nextDouble();
        }   
        //Get and validate pay rate from employees.
        System.out.print("Enter the pay rate of employee: ");
        payRate[i]=keyboard.nextDouble();
        while(payRate[i]<10.24)
        {
            System.out.println("Error. Minimum pay rate must be at least $10.24");
            System.out.print("Please enter the pay rate: ");
            payRate[i]=keyboard.nextDouble();
        }
    }
    calculateWages(employeeWages, employeeHours, payRate);
    System.out.println("Gross Wages:");
    System.out.println();
    for(int i=0;i<employeeID.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%-9d%-7s",employeeID[i],employeeWages[i]);
    }

}
    public static String[] calculateWages(double[] employeeWages, double[] inputHours,double[] payRate)
    {   
    String[] formatWage = new String[7];
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("$###.00");
    for(int i = 1;i<employeeWages.length;i++)
        {
        employeeWages[i]=inputHours[i]*payRate[i];
        formatWage[i]=formatter.format(employeeWages[i]);
        }
    return formatWage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please be specific about your question and post a minimal example.

Comment: In order to get array from other method, simply set an array to it.

Answer (score 0):

calculateWages is returning an array so set an array equal to it

```
String [] result = calculateWages(employeeWages, employeeHours, payRate);
```